# Node.js require JSON from web address?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, https

I am trying to load JSON data from https://blockchain.info/ticker into Node like so: `const btc = require(https://blockchain.info/ticker)` Obviously, this does not work. How can one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `require()` a URL.  It needs a filename.

If you want to load some JSON from a remote server, you can use the `request` or `request-promise` packages.  The loading will be asynchronous though so you will need to use the result in the appropriate callback.  Here's an example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

rp({json: true}, "https://blockchain.info/ticker").then(data => {
    // use data here
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
    console.log(err);
});
```